# Disable animations completely for an application UWP

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I know there is **Windows level setting** to disable animations. And **yes** we can disable animations for individual controls by modifying **style**. I can remove animations for each control. But seems to be not efficient.

Is there any API provided in the SDK to disable animation completely for particular application.?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such api could disable your app's animation. As you said Windows setting provide system level to disable all the animation. I think this is good feature request, Please feel free post your requirement with FeedBackHub app.